# What does "that public schoolboy polish" mean here?

Tags: meaning, british-english, literature

I would like to know what "that public schoolboy polish" means in the following sentences:

> ‘Yup,’ Will says. ‘We were at school together.’ I’m surprised. The
> other men have **that public schoolboy polish**, while Johnno seems
> rougher – no cut-glass accent.
>
> ‘Trevellyan’s,’ Femi says. ‘It was like that book with all the boys on
> a desert island together, killing each other, oh Christ, what’s it
> called—’
>
> ‘*Lord of the Flies*,’ Charlie says, the faintest trace of superiority
> in his tone. *I might have gone to state school, it says, but I’m
> better read than you.*

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 12

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, Hannah, the wife of Charlie (Jules' friend), arrived at the island and is now at the dinner party for the rehearsal dinner with only some selected guests. And during the party, Hannah hears how almost all the ushers went to the same school as Will.

In this part, I wonder what "public schoolboy polish" means.
Does it perhaps mean that they have a sheen, a particular shine that would emanate from public schoolboys...?

But then, this is my small question, but is it right to understand that "public school" here actually means exclusive private schools in the UK, like Eton? This might be a fundamental question, but I am just wondering why it is "public" school when it is actually a "private" school.

Comment: Can public be adjective to 'polish' and not 'schoolboy'? I have the same doubts as 'private shcools' would better fit the description

Comment: No.  In the UK Public schools are old, grand, fee-charging schools like Eton, Harrow or Rugby.

Comment: @JamesK ok thanks, that shed light on the matter!

Comment: **Polish** doesn't necessarily describe something physically shiny.  One of the [standard definitions of **polish**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polish) is "freedom from rudeness or coarseness : CULTURE."

Comment: These public schools (elite, very expensive) offer merit scholarships. Scholars board with princes (Philip + Charles at Gordonstoun, William + Harry at Eaton). The philosophy is to turn the coarse scholars into gentlemen that could converse with princes in the same accent. You can think of the adjective 'public' as meaning 'open' (and as opposed to private clubs). You can tell public school boys by their accent like you can tell birds by their song. It's that crazy.

Comment: This would likely have much greater future value if it were split across 2 separate question posts: 1) What are "public schools" in the UK? 2) What does "polish" mean here? Although the first question could probably easily be answered with a quick Google search.

Comment: The term _public schools_ reveals a great deal about just how aristocratic the Old Establishment is in the UK. By _public_ it is apparent that _anyone can go there_ (ie. not just the most elite landed gentry). The idea that the huge fees might be an obstacle to many simply does not occur - it goes without saying that _"anyone"_ means _"everyone who can afford the fees"_ Those who cannot, are, at the very least, not upstanding enough to belong to _"anyone"_ though, very probably, they are just off the radar, completely. [1/2]

Comment: My favourite phrase which makes sense in both British English and American English (but means something completely different in each) is _"Middle class children go to Public School"_ which, in American English, means _"Children from normal working families go to state-run schools"_ and, in British English, means _"Posh, rich kids go to exclusive, expensive schools."_ [2/2]

Comment: @Rounin no, public school meant that is not a guild school, so you don't have to be in a guild to go there. "the most elite landed gentry" had private tutors and so did not require schools.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - Yes, you are right - my bracketed qualifier is ill-worded. (I simply meant to emphasise what _"anyone"_ meant in this instance.) It's certainly the case that not requiring schools continues (almost) to the present day. In the mid-eighties it was a little radical that the Princess of Wales insisted that the young Prince William enter the public school system at kindergarten age rather than being home-schooled.

Comment: Thank you very much everybody for the explanations! Such a shame that I cannot choose all the answers and comments as accepted answers... All of your explanations are really helpful and informative. I learned many new things about public schools and private schools in British and American English all thanks to you. I sincerely appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you go back 300 years or so, most people didn't get any education.  Only the wealthy could afford it.

There were two types of education: Private education, at home with a tutor. Or Public education at a school.  These schools became known as "public schools"  in contrast to private tutoring.   But they were always fee-charging schools.

Other types of school

- "State school" (a school funded by the government, so no school fees)
- "Private school" (a fee-charging school, but less grand than the public schools).  Also "Independent school".
- "Grammar School" A state school that has an entrance exam.
- "Comprehensive school" A state school that doesn't select by entrance exam.
- "Academy" A school funded by the government but run by private organisation.
- "Faith School" A school funded by the government but run by a church or other religious organisation.

"Public school polish" is the accent, style, manner that boys learn at public school.

Comment: Your explanation of the origin of the term public is slightly different from e.g. what Wikipedia says: *"Public schools emerged from charity schools established to educate poor scholars — public because access to them was not restricted on the basis of religion, occupation, or home location, and that they were subject to public management or control, in contrast to private schools which were run for the personal profit of the proprietors."* And to be clear, public schools are a subset of private/independent schools 

Comment: In my experience I've noticed that some BrE speakers may not be aware of the term "public school", and I've sometimes heard it used to mean "state school", perhaps following the comparable AmE term for government-funded schools in the US.

Comment: "grammer schools" can be either state or private depending on where in the country you are and the history of the particular school.

Comment: You only need go back 50 years.

Comment: @Tim Re: Wikipedia: The citation given on that line doesn't seem to support what they've said, though.

Comment: Pretty amazing how completely different the terms for different types of schools are between BrE and AmE. They all either mean something different here or don't even exist.

Comment: @Barmar as an American I'm still trying to wrap my head around a british Public School being a fee-paying institution, which is exactly what a Private School in the USA is. I've read the wiki and etymology and still just have to accept the difference.

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around how 'mericans say "could care less" to mean "couldn't care less".

Comment: @user3067860 Thanks for the tip - can you give more details? I don't have an OED subscription, so can't see it.

Comment: @user3067860 Further digging... the Definition section of the Public School article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_school_(United_Kingdom)#Definition suggests OP is right after all: *There is no single or absolute definition of a public school, and the use of the term has varied over time and according to context. The starting point was the contrast between a public school and private teaching.* It links to this source: http://www.educationengland.org.uk/documents/fleming/fleming.html#11 which is part of the Fleming Report from the 1940s

Comment: @Tim Notably the OED page doesn't have the word "charity" or "poor" anywhere. There are a couple of mentions of "free" schools in the BrE section but it's not really clear that public = free or if they are actually separate things. Like this reference: "1604 Act 1 Jas. I c. 4 §8   No person shall keepe any schoole..except it be in some publike or free Grammer Schoole, or in some such noblemans..or gentlemans..house as are not recusants." The only thing that's really clear is that they've got some element of public (government) control and they're extremely expensive now.

Answer (score 25):

*Public schools* in the UK are fee-paying schools, of which Eton and Harrow are probably the most prestigious (but there are many less expensive ones). For an explanation of the name, see [the Wikipedia page under 'Early history'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_school_(United_Kingdom)#Early_History).

*Polish* refers to a metaphorical 'sheen', a poise acquired from attendance at a prestigious school.

Comment: And Prime Minister Johnson is quite clearly the most polished of them.

Comment: This is interesting to me as a native American English speaker, because here public schools are the normal free tuition K-12th grade schools and are differentiated from private schools that are costly and posh. In American English you'd swap public for private to have this sentence be easily understood here in the US.

Comment: @jdf What you call _"public schools"_ we call _"state schools"_.

Comment: @jdf You shouldn't just swap the terms: public schools *are* private schools, just a particularly elite subset of them (called "public" for strange historical reasons). So the translation BrE-> AmE should be: 1) private school -> private school 2) public school -> **elite** private school 3) state school -> public school

Comment: @jdf maybe a helpful comparison would be the status and prestige Ivy League schools have among US colleges; it's an historical grouping but one that's stuck around. (But to be clear, UK public schools are for secondary education (age 11-18); our Ivy League equivalent for higher education is probably Oxbridge, ie Oxford and Cambridge... or maybe the Russell Group)

Answer (score 12):

In short: it means you have the accent and mannerisms of a posh upper-class person.

---

The other answers cover the basics, but I don't think emphasise enough the role of public schools in maintaining the UK's fairly rigid class structure. For example, 7% of the population of the UK go to private schools (which, confusingly, is a category which includes public schools), but [as of 2017 29% of members of parliament did](https://www.channel4.com/news/factcheck/factcheck-qa-how-posh-is-parliament) (and 74% of judges, from the next source). The families of public school attendees are significantly wealthier than the average (from [this](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2019/jan/13/public-schools-david-kynaston-francis-green-engines-of-privilege) article arguing against them):

> What particularly defines British private education is its extreme social exclusivity. Only about 6% of the UK’s school population attend such schools, and the families accessing private education are highly concentrated among the affluent. At every rung of the income ladder there are a small number of private-school attenders; but it is only at the very top, above the 95th rung of the ladder – where families have an income of at least £120,000 – that there are appreciable numbers of private-school children. At the 99th rung – families with incomes upwards of £300,000 – six out of every 10 children are at private school. A glance at the annual fees is relevant here. The press focus tends to be on the great and historic boarding schools – such as Eton (basic fee £40,668 in 2018–19), Harrow (£40,050) and Winchester (£39,912) – but it is important to see the private sector in the less glamorous round, and stripped of the extra cost of boarding. In 2018 the average day fees at prep schools were, at £13,026, around half the income of a family on the middle rung of the income ladder. For secondary school, and even more so sixth forms, the fees are appreciably higher. In short, access to private schooling is, for the most part, available only to wealthy households. Indeed, the small number of income-poor families going private can only do so through other sources: typically, grandparents’ assets and/or endowment-supported bursaries from some of the richest schools. Overwhelmingly, pupils at private schools are rubbing shoulders with those from similarly well-off backgrounds.

This segregation of the population, largely along lines of wealth/prestige, leads to attributes which are shared by the segment of the population who do go to these private schools. The received pronunciation accent (aka Queen's English) was actually first referred to as "Public School Pronunciation" in 1917, for example.

Comment: "average day fees". Should it be annual? 13000 quids a day seems high, even for "public" schools.

Comment: @EricDuminil It probably means 'for day pupils' (not boarders) rather than 'fees per day'

Answer (score 3):

Public school "polish and mixability" is also, at Eton, referred to as "oiling".

> It wasn’t just Boris. Two years later, David Cameron arrived and I was
> immediately struck by his bottomless well of self-confidence. Nearly
> all the products of major public schools I encountered at Oxford
> possessed this savoir-faire.
>
> At Britain’s best public schools, children don’t merely learn how to
> conjugate Greek verbs, they’re taught how to be successful adults as
> well. I don’t just mean they’re taught manners — though God knows
> that’s important — I mean **they’re told how to win friends and
> influence people.** At Eton this is referred to as ‘oiling’ and I
> imagine there are other words to describe the same thing at similar
> schools. Politics isn’t on the curriculum — it’s the sort of soft
> subject that’s only taught in the state sector — but it’s the no. 1
> extra-curricular activity. Most of the public schoolboys I met at
> Oxford had spent the previous five years clambering over one another
> in an effort to become the president of this and the captain of that.
> As a result, they’d mastered the art of self-advancement.

https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/status-anxiety-the-etonian-difference

Comment: Could this be where the phrase, "He's an oily bastard, right enough" comes from? :-)

Comment: Recent British history has taught us that British public schools equip their students not only with self-confidence and savoir faire, but also a sense of entitlement.